# Disable next track auto play on track end - Cue WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, audio, media-player

I'm looking to disable the next track auto-playing on a Cue plugin playlist. When looking for how to do this, the solution previously used by others no longer works as the code changed since.

I found the code bit in the plugin files that dictates that the next track should auto play, but I do not understand how to prevent it / what to add to my theme's js file to prevent it.

On line 577 of the file jquery.cue.js :

```
// Play the next track when one ends.
                            $media.on( 'ended.cue', function() {
                                    var index = player.cueCurrentTrack + 1 >= player.options.cuePlaylistTracks.length ? 0 : player.cueCurrentTrack + 1;
    
                                    // Determine if the playlist shouldn't loop.
                                    if ( ! player.options.cuePlaylistLoop && 0 === index ) {
                                            return;
                                    }
    
                                    // Give other 'end' events a chance to grab the current track.
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $( player.node ).trigger( 'nextTrack.cue', player );
                                            player.cuePlayNextTrack();
                                    }, 250 );
                            });
```

This is the file: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/cue/trunk/assets/js/vendor/jquery.cue.js

This is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cue/

This is the previous solution: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-stop-playing-at-the-end-of-each-track/

Do you know what code I could add to my jquery theme file to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking for an answer, this is what I've ended up with that works:

If you have a js file inside your child theme:

```
   var endedHandler = function () {
        var playHandler = function () {
            $(".cue-audio")[0].pause();
            $(".cue-audio").unbind("play", playHandler);
            $(".cue-audio").unbind("play", endedHandler);           
        }
        $(this).on("play", playHandler);
    }
    $(".cue-audio").on("ended", endedHandler);
});
```

If you don't and need to add it somewhere else:

```
jQuery(".cue-audio").on("ended", function () {
var playHandler = function () {
jQuery(".cue-audio")[0].pause();
jQuery(".cue-audio").unbind("play", playHandler);
}
jQuery(this).on("play", playHandler);
});
```